# Move mainwindow while clicking on button

Tags: c++, winapi

I have subclassed a button and I'm trying to move her parent window around while this button is being hold down.

I'm having difficulty in how to proper calculate the new window position in this line:

`MoveWindow(hWnd, pt.x, pt.y, width, height, TRUE);`

```
// hWnd represent the button parent window.

switch (message)
{

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    POINT p{};
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    ::SetCapture(hWnd);
    mousedown = true;
}
break;

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    if (mousedown)
    {
        RECT r;
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);
        pt.x -= x;
        pt.y -= y;

        int width = r.right - r.left;
        int height = r.bottom - r.top;
        MoveWindow(hWnd, pt.x, pt.y, width, height, TRUE); // this is completely wrong, but im confused about how to proper calculate it
    }
}
break;

case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    ReleaseCapture();
    mousedown = false;
}
break;
```

The code is partially working, the window is being moved, but to an incorrect position relative to where the mouse is.

--Edit new code--

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    POINT p{};
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    dragging = true;
    SetCapture(hWnd);
}
break;

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        RECT r;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);

        int w = r.right - r.left;
        int h = r.bottom - r.top;

        POINT p{};
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        p.x -= w/2;
        p.y -= h/2;

        MoveWindow(hWnd, p.x, p.y, w, h, TRUE);
    }
}
break;

case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    ReleaseCapture();
    dragging = false;
}
break;
```

It closer, but the window is 'jumping' down when clicked-moved

Comment: You are mixing coordinates. Remember, [`GetCursorPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) returns _screen_ coordinates. When you mouse down, record _both_ the initial window position and the cursor position. In your mouse move, adjust the window position relative to the _initial window position_. Calculate the offset from the current cursor position and the initial cursor position.

Comment: @Dúthomhas see new code i've added, the window is jumping, still calculating it wrong?

Comment: You will want to read the documentation more carefully. [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown): *"Do not use the `LOWORD` or `HIWORD` macros to extract the x- and y- coordinates of the cursor position because these macros return incorrect results on systems with multiple monitors."* Same for `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

Comment: @IInspectable it still jumping a bit, any idea why?

Comment: Why aren't you using the cursor coordinates passed into your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message handlers?

Comment: @IInspectable Because using them it didnt moved to the correct position

Comment: You can send WM_NCHITTEST message to the parent.

Comment: I need to achieve it with these messages above

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) also tells you what to use instead of `HIWORD` and `LOWORD`: [`GET_X_LPARAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-get_x_lparam) and [`GET_Y_LPARAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-get_y_lparam). Still, moving the parent window in response to child control interactions is going to get confusing. Child controls are positioned relative to their parent, and if the parent moves so will the children.

Comment: It's much easier to pass the job to the DefWindowProc function. But if you insist on doing it yourself, I recommend using the global mouse move event and its coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, again, stop messing with local coordinates. When you press the button, get the global window position and the global mouse position. Then in every mouse motion event, reposition the global window relative to the difference in global mouse position.

Comment: There is a MUCH easier way to implement this, by simply sending the parent window an (undocumented) `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE)` message and let it handle the dragging for you, as-if the user were dragging the window by its titlebar normally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When i should send `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE)` in response to `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`?     `case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:    {   SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, WPARAM(0xF012), 0);    }` didnt move

Comment: @Nathan because you are sending the message to the wrong `HWND`. You are sending it to the button itself, but you need to send it the button's top-level parent window instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `hWnd` in my previous comment belongs to the 'main window'. I'm testing your suggestion into the `wndproc`, while clicking into the window background and handling `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`

Comment: @Nathan I know for a fact that `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE)` works.  I've used it many times, and there are plenty of questions on StackOverflow that demonstrate its use. Try calling `ReleaseCapture()` before sending the message. However, if you are clicking on the parent window's background directly, then it would be easier to catch `WM_NCHITTEST` and have it return `HTCAPTION`. Sending `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE)` is more commonly used when clicking on a child control instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau when i send `ReleaseCapture()` it does work. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation seems incorrect to me. When you down the mouse button, you should calculate the difference between the desktop mouse position and the location of the parent window and when you move the mouse, you can add the difference to the desktop mouse position back.

```
POINT g_deltaXY;

switch (message)
{

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    POINT p{};
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
    g_deltaXY.x = rect.left - p.x;
    g_deltaXY.y = rect.top - p.y; 
    ::SetCapture(hWnd);
    mousedown = true;
}
break;
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    if (mousedown)
    {
        RECT r;
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt); 
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);

        int width = r.right - r.left;
        int height = r.bottom - r.top;

        MoveWindow(hWnd, pt.x + g_deltaXY.x, pt.y + g_deltaXY.y, width, height, TRUE);
    }
}
break;
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    ReleaseCapture();
    mousedown = false;
}
break;
```